# Disable 0 key on softkeyboard for first time

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to disable the number `0` key on soft keyboard for first time when an user clicks on `EditText`.

The `EditText` has an `input type` `number` and i have to input a ten digit phone number where the first digit should not be zero.

Please suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: Y is everything in bold btw?  anyways, you can find out weather the 0 is clicked or not. so if the 0 is cliked then dont do any work there.

Comment: I dont think you can disable 0, but you can check if first input is zero than set edit text blank by usin text watcher.

Comment: you have to put validation not restriction . So dont do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    boolean changing = false;

    EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             if (!changing && edit.getText().toString().startsWith("0")){
                changing = true;
                edit.setText(edit.getText().toString().replace("0", ""));
             }
             changing = false; 
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        } 

    });
```

Comment: after if end why did you set changing = false can you please explain?

Comment: the 'changing' flag is for avoiding 'if (...) block' to process again when we call 'edit.setText()'. Removing the flag would cause the infinity loop.

Answer (score 1):

EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.medittext);
        edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             String input = editable.toString();
            if (input.length() > 0 && input.charAt(0) == '0') {
                editable.replace(0, 1, "");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use your "0" handling at "onTextChanged"  .use this code:

```
 if(arg0.length()>0){
    if(arg0.charAt(0)=='0'){
        your_edittext.setText("");
    }
}
```